# How to use a Java library with KMM (Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile)

Tags: java, kotlin, nfc, kotlin-multiplatform, st25

I am developing an **Android** application that uses the **ST25 library** to read **NFC** ST tags. I would like to **port my application** also to **iOS** using **KMM**, a **cross-platform** solution based on **Kotlin**. The **ST25 library** is written in **Java** and I don't know if I can use it with KMM or if I should look for an alternative. The ST25 sdk includes an .aar and a .jar.

My question is, can I use the ST25 library with KMM?If yes, how can I integrate it into my project?If not, is there an equivalent library written in Kotlin or another language compatible with KMM?

I tried to do some research online and found only old posts about it and wanted to know if there were any updates regarding the use of Java libraries in KKM.

Comment: As a side note, the name Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) was deprecated in favor of Kotlin Multiplaform (KMP): https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2023/07/update-on-the-name-of-kotlin-multiplatform/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iOS version of your app will not run on the JVM, it runs natively on iOS. Therefore you cannot use JVM libraries in your iOS app.

That said, the Kotlin multiplatform technology does allow you to write common code that calls some functions/APIs that have a different implementation on different platform.

This means that, if you find an iOS library to do this, you could define the common API you need as `expect` declarations in common code, and then write the `actual` implementations in the JVM source set by delegating to the ST25 JVM library, and other `actual` implementations in the iOS source set by delegating to the iOS library.

Comment: Restating the answer a bit. Definitely correct, but to summarize, you have the JVM ST25 library. There almost certainly is an iOS equivalent. To talk to them from shared Kotlin code, I'd write an interface with only the functions you need from shared code. For each platform, implement that interface and pass it in on app start. expect/actual is rigid, generally, and cinterop on iOS isn't fun. Talk about this (title on the page is wrong but the video is correct): https://www.droidcon.com/2022/06/28/sdk-design-and-publishing-for-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile/

Comment: That's a very useful addition, thanks! I don't have first hand experience with iOS development (neither with Swift nor Kotlin), so I haven't faced the "reality" of these issues.